# What are some examples of advanced Dark Magic in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, dark-arts

I'm referring to Dark Magic spells which are either very advanced and hard to perform or require great and morally questionable sacrifices or both.

An obvious example are Horcruxes, but I was wondering what other similar spells and examples of Dark Magic exist.

Answer (score 13):

Well, first of all, you obviously have the **Unforgivable Curses** :

- [Cruciatus Curse](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Cruciatus_Curse) (*Crucio*)
- [Imperius Curse](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Imperius_Curse) (*Imperio*)
- [Killing Curse](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Killing_Curse) (*Avada Kedavra*)

**Hexes** and **Jinxes**, while less powerful, are also considered as Dark Spells :

- [Knockback Jinx](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Knockback_Jinx) (*Flipendo*)
- [Oppugno Jinx](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Oppugno_Jinx) (*Oppugno*)
- [Revulsion Jinx](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Revulsion_Jinx) (*Relashio*)
- [Bat-Bogey Hex](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Bat-Bogey_Hex)
- [Stinging Hex](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Stinging_Jinx)
- [Toenail-growing Hex](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Toenail-growing_hex)
- *And probably many others*

We could probably add other spells, such as [Sectumsempra](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sectumsempra), [Morsmordre](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Morsmordre) or [Fiendfyre](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fiendfyre).

There are also some **potions** identified as Dark :

- [Rudimentary Body potion](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Rudimentary_body_potion)
- [Rebirth potion](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Regeneration_potion)
- [Drink of Despair](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Emerald_Potion)

We could also add **dark objects** to the list, which are supposedly-normal objects enchanted with a dark curse. Such examples include :

- [Horcruxes](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Horcrux)
- [Hand of Glory](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hand_of_Glory)
- The [Opal Necklace](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Opal_Necklace) used to curse Katie Bell
- The [Black Quill](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Quill) used by Umbridge in Harry's detentions

One could also argue that some creatures, such as [Dementors](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dementor) or [Inferi](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Inferius) are **dark creatures**.

And finally, some **practices** are entirely devoted to the Dark Arts, such as [Necromancy](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Necromancy).

*All those examples were taken from the [HP Dark Arts Wikia page](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Arts) (which I know is not canon, but this particular page seems all right to me), where you can find others examples of dark objects, creatures and practices.*

Comment: Welcome! This is a fantastic answer!

Comment: One minor quibble, maybe include some canonical sources describing Hexes and Jinxes or Sectumsempra and specific potions as dark?

Comment: A good answer. Sectumsepra is probably the most clearcut example of a dark spell. I'm not sure spells like the Bat Bogey Hex count, though.

Comment: OP asked specifically for _really_ advanced technical kinds of magic, which most wizards can't do. Any old wizard can perform a Stinging Hex or a Knockback Jinx, and arguably a lot of Wizards can even perform the killing curse (it isn't a complicated spell, you just have to mean it)

Comment: What about Fiendfyre? The enchanted fire used by Crabbe (I think) in the Deathly Hallows, in the RoR. Hermione said that it is one of the things that can destroy Horcruxes, but is really dangerous (and dark).

Comment: Hexes and jinxes **more** powerful? Than the Unforgivable Curses? I do believe something's not quite right there…

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Right, I meant **less** powerful but got lost somehow, thanks. I'll add Fiendfyre and try to search for canon sources, especially for the *Hexes and Jinxes* part, but if anybody finds them first, please feel free to edit my answer ;)

Comment: Killing a unicorn , possessing someone’s body(quirrel) , putting nagini in bathilda bagshot’s corpse can also be added.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some examples of things described in the books as Dark Magic:

### Philosopher's Stone

- **Broomstick tampering**

  > "Can't have," Hagrid said, his voice shaking. "Can't nothing interfere with a broomstick  except powerful Dark Magic — no kid could do that to a Nimbus Two Thousand."

### Chamber of Secrets

- **Petrification**

  > "No second year could have done this," said Dumbledore firmly. "It would take Dark Magic of the most advanced —"
- **Method of opening the Chamber of Secrets**

  > "But, professor," piped up Parvati Patil, "you'd probably have to use Dark Magic to open it —"
- **Diary containing sentient memories**

  > Why didn't you show the diary to me, or your mother? A suspicious object like that, it was *clearly* full of Dark Magic —"

### Prisoner of Azkaban

- **Insulting parchment**

  > "This parchment is plainly full of Dark Magic. This is supposed to be your area of expertise, Lupin. Where do you imagine Potter got such a thing?"
- **Method of escaping Azkaban**

  > "If you don't mind me asking, how — how did you get out of Azkaban, if you didn't use Dark Magic?"
- **Creating doubles**

  > "Harry, what do you think you'd do if you saw yourself bursting into Hagrid's house?" said Hermione.
  >
  > "I'd — I'd think I's gone mad," said Harry, "or I'd think there was some Dark Magic going on —"

### Goblet of Fire

- **Parseltounge**

  > Parseltounge, the ability to converse with snakes, has long been considered a Dark Art.
- **Flesh, Blood, and Bone potion**

  > "I knew that to achieve this — it is an old piece of Dark Magic, the potion that revived me tonight —I would need three powerful ingredients.

### Half-Blood Prince

- **Cursed necklace**

  > They're used to find Dark Magic and Dark objects. They'd have picked up a powerful curse, like the one on that necklace, within seconds.
- **Horcruxes**

  > "They must be really advanced Dark Magic, or why would Voldemort have wanted to know about them?
- **Sectumsempra**

  > "Who would have thought you knew such Dark Magic? Who taught you that spell?"

Answer (score -3):

The Obscurus, It is the darkest piece of magic

Comment: An Obscurus is a bit of an odd case because whilst it is described as a dark force it isn't something that everyone can use, but a good addition. Could you also [edit] this to expand on this a bit as it's quite terse at the moment? For example, a quote describing an Obscurus would be good.

Comment: Also, is that really Harry Potter canon, or Fantastic Beasts canon?